# Removing and adding the same symlink in perforce

Tags: perforce

I have a symlink something like
sym_dir -> dir_2020_05_07
where sym_dir is the symlink mapped to original dir dir_2020_05_07.

This sym_dir and "dir_2020_05_07" is added to perforce (symdir is added by 'p4 add -t symlink sym_dir').

I have created another dir with today's date as follows: dir_2020_05_13.
Now I want to link sym_dir to dir_2020_05_13 and update the perforce as well.(Of course I will commit 
dir_2020_05_13 to perforce).

How can I do that in a single go?

```
p4 delete sym_dir
p4 add -t symlink sym_dir
p4 delete dir_2020_05_07/
find dir_2020_05_13 -name "*" | xargs p4 add
```

However p4 is not allowing to add and delete the same "sym_dir" as a part of single go (single change_list).

How can I achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To modify a file in a single revision, use `p4 edit` instead of `p4 add` + `p4 delete`.

Comment: Thanks. How can I use p4 edit in this case? p4 edit -t symlink sym_dir? Or p4 edit -y symlink sym_dir dir_2020_05_13?

Comment: `p4 edit symlink` to tell Perforce you're modifying the symlink, then do whatever you want with the symlink (use `ln` or whatever other tool), then `p4 submit`.  `p4` itself isn't an editor, it just stores whatever you create.

Comment: @Samwise The p4 edit command should include `-t` before symlink.

Comment: `symlink` refers here to the name of the file, not the type.  I guess I should have said `p4 edit sym_dir`.  The argument is just whatever the name of the file is.  In any case `-t symlink` isn't needed because the file is already a symlink; files maintain their type unless explicitly changed by using `-t` with a *different* type.